# Can't set JSON data in react state

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, reactjs

So I'm trying to set a JSON object into a state but it continuously gives an empty object. Can't figure out why.

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'

const MainApp = () => {

    const [products, setProducts] = useState({})
    const url = "http://localhost:5000/products"

    fetch(url)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(res => setProducts(res))
        .catch(err => { console.log(err) })
         
        console.log(products) //this gives an empty object

}

export default MainApp
```

This is the output in http://localhost:5000/products

```
[
  {
    "id": "trYl7JYATH0",
    "description": "Test caption",
    "imgThumb": "test.jpg",
    "img": "test.jpg",
    "link": "test.jpg",
    "userId": "X0ygkSu4Sxo",
    "userName": "user",
    "userLink": "https://unsplash.com/@user",
    "tags": [
      "building",
      "architecture",
      "corner",
      "black",
      "dark",
      "balcony",
      "night"
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: What does res.json() return?

Comment: `fetch(url)` is asynchronous. You start the fetch, but your program continues with the next statement `console.log()` when your state is still empty. You can google async/await fetch for further reading

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't make a network request in the main function. There is a hook provided by React, called `useEffect`.

```js
import React, {
  useState,
  useEffect
} from 'react';

const MainApp = () => {

  const [products, setProducts] = useState([]) //API returning array
  const url = "http://localhost:5000/products"

  useEffect(() => {
    // Update the document title using the browser API
    fetch(url)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(res => setProducts(res))
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
      })
  }, []); //This function will run at the last, when all componenets rendered in browser
}

ReactDOM.render( <
  MainApp / > ,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Your answer is not correct. You wrapped `useEffect` in `fetchDataFromServer` and it should be the other way round

Comment: Oh got it. I will fix

Comment: Still not correct. `fetchDataFromServer` is not defined as a const